# Angular Animate - Switch testimony

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML with Angular 1.3.8 [Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/xwuorJB0ZTyuXquE1FsY?p=preview):

```
<div class="testimonials" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="testimonial" ng-repeat="testimonial in testimonials" ng-animate>
    <blockquote>
      <p ng-bind="testimonial.text"></p>
      <cite ng-bind="testimonial.author"></cite>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.testimonial.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.testimonial.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.testimonial.ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}
.testimonial.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

I would like to have an anchor for each testimony and change it ...

But somehow this does not seem to work.

What am I missing?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? I had to add an `ng-app="plunker"` to your plunker to see anything.

Comment: Oops I posted the link without updating that .. But the problem is this: I would like to have on A tag for each testimonial. And one A tag is clicked the correspondent testimonial will show. Now all 2 at the same time. And I would like to use Angular animate for this.

Comment: So, [like this?](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZRggSOZrNMiYuWmdjBjc?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get the animations to work without some serious trial and error. Basically, I got rid of the `ng-animate` attribute and `testimonial` class on the `ng-repeat` element. Then I added an `ng-show` directive to the `blockquote` element. The `ng-animate` directive is actually unnecessary as long as our CSS is correct.

New HTML:

```
<div class="testimonials" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="testimonial in testimonials">
    <a href="" ng-click="show($index)">{{testimonial.author}}</a>
    <blockquote class="testimonial" ng-show="testimonial.shouldShow">
      <p ng-bind="testimonial.text"></p>
      <cite ng-bind="testimonial.author"></cite>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```

New Javascript to execute the `show` function:

```
$scope.show = function(index) {
  for (var t in $scope.testimonials) {
    $scope.testimonials[t].shouldShow = false;
  }

  $scope.testimonials[index].shouldShow = true;
};
```

Then the CSS classes needed to be adjusted to use `ng-hide-*` instead of `ng-enter` and `ng-remove`. This is because the basic idea (as I understood it from the question) is not to animate the contents of the list but rather *details* of each list item.

New CSS (note the transitions):

```
.testimonial.ng-hide-add,
.testimonial.ng-hide-add-active,
.testimonial.ng-hide-remove,
.testimonial.ng-hide-remove-active {
  -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
  -moz-transition:0.5s linear all;
  -o-transition:0.5s linear all;
  transition:0.5s linear all;
}

.testimonial.ng-hide-add {
  opacity: 1;
}
.testimonial.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
.testimonial.ng-hide-remove {
  opacity: 0;
}
.testimonial.ng-hide-remove-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

It might be useful for future readers to point out that the animations will only work if you include a script tag for [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) (it's not built in) and declare a dependency on it in your `angular.module` setup.

Example HTML in `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

Example `module` call:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ngAnimate"]);
```

Comment: I though that Animate was included in Angular 1.3.x and that angular-animate.js was necessary only on 1.2.x. That is why I didn't use it.

Comment: Maybe. Angular docs are known to be pretty bad. I just pulled that info from the "Installation" section of the doc page linked in the answer. The page I'm looking at is tagged as version 1.4.0.

Comment: Also [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations): *Animations are not available unless you include the ngAnimate module as a dependency within your application.*

Comment: Of course, that might just mean you need the `module("name", ["ngAnimate"])` part, not necessarily the `<script>` tag.

Comment: I read somewhere in Angular docs that from 1.3 animate was included ... But yes, their docs are not very good. Is your ng-hide approach compatible with older browsers? I mean can I use the JS fallback with it?

Comment: I honestly don't know. You should try it before pushing to production.